# Command \leqslant with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How to use the command `\leqslant` with pgfplots ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{mycolor}{cmyk}{0.00,0.18,0.29,0.02}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{dnorm}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 [domain=0:10,
 samples=500,
 height=5cm,
 width=10cm,
 axis lines*=left,
 enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
 every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
 every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
 style=thick,
 ] 

\addplot [fill=mycolor, draw, domain=3:4.75] {dnorm(4,1)} \closedcycle;               
\addplot [thick, smooth] {dnorm(4,1)};

\node (a) at (axis cs:3,-0.03) {$a$};
\node (b) at (axis cs:4.75,-0.03) {$b$};

\node (title) at (axis cs:4,0.45) {$P(a\leq X \leq b )$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` in preamble.